# Custom Operation Function

Tags: jquery, html, function, javascript

Im trying to create a little function for my use that is suppose to get the Text of the chosen element. If the element has Math in is than my function is suppose to do the math and append to the answer to the element of your choice.

My really simple function is:

```
function op2(id, end){
      var he = $(id).text();
      $(end).html(he);
}
```

This would be used like this:

```
function la() {
op2('#default', '#here');
}
```

With the following html:

```
<div id="default">10+3</div>
<div onclick="la();">Test</div>
<div id="here"></div>
```

This is the problem, when its suppose to add all it is doing is adding the 10+3 to the element `#here` instead of displaying `13`.

I know that the problem is that the browser appends the text of `#default` to `#here` like this, `'10+3'` but I don't know how to change that.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kS6qR/2/)

Comment: You have to write your own code to examine the `.text()` result, find mathematical expressions in it, evaluate those expressions and put the resulting text into the output.  jQuery doesn't do that part for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this simple case, use eval() function on the content of the first element. See the link for tweaked version: http://jsfiddle.net/4DF3k/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the datatype of your variables is String and not Integer. If you would like to use the + as an arithmetic operation instead of the string append operation you must cast your variable to an integer or float

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm#parseInt

This link will tell you more about it.

Simply use the Javascript functions parseInt and parseFloat

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery Calculations plugin [here](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm).

For more complex mathematical equations and different operations it should give you a good starting point to evaluate the `$.text()` of the selector.

I hope this helps!